# Cannot use Using Statement

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I am using Visual Studio 2005 and am unable to use the "Using" statement. I have just moved some code over from a .net 4 application, but that does not seem to be the problem as it is still not usable in a new app.

```
Using sw as StreamWriter = new StreamWriter(userFile2)
    For each blah as blahblah in blah()
        sw.WriteLine(blah)
    sw.Close()
End Using
```

Error = Using is not declared
I am lead to believe that it should work the exact same as in VB 2010.

Comment: That code on its own looks fine and compiles in VS2005. Is there any other code around it that is breaking it?

Comment: Hmmm that was odd. Either I was in somethign wrong? but a computer restart fixed it. That was confusing sorry guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems compile fine for me (VS 2005/.Net 2.0). You are missing `Next` for the `For Each`. Also you don't have to explicitly call `Close()` for `sw`, the `Using` block take care of it.

```
Using sw as StreamWriter = new StreamWriter(userFile2)
    For each blah as blahblah in blah()
        sw.WriteLine(blah)
    Next
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you are doing this in Visual Studio 2005.  Are you working in .NET 1.1 or .NET 2.0?  I don't believe that the USING keyword is available in .NET 1.1.

Comment: If you are using VS 2005 you have 2.0 and you can only compile in 2.0.  VS 2008 is the first to allow different target .net frameworks.